# Allowing a MySQL user to grant themselves privileges to a new database

Tags: mysql, privileges

I have a MySQL user, which we'll call Tom. Tom has global CREATE and SHOW DATABASES privileges, with the 'GRANT' option.
The user is assigned SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE privileges on a per-database basis. However, after Tom creates a new database, he can't set his SELECT etc. privileges, despite having a global GRANT option.
The error is (predictably) :

```
CREATE DATABASE `my_new_db`; -- this is fine
GRANT SELECT , INSERT , UPDATE , DELETE ON `my_new_db` . * TO 'Tom'@'%';
*Access denied for user 'Tom'@'%' to database 'my_new_db'*
```

This is being done via PHP, but I doubt that makes much difference.

Someone tell me what I'm doing wrong! Ta =]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't grant privileges you don't have.  Tom needs to have global SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE privileges in order to grant them to others.

Comment: Really? That's properly daft. So basically I have to create a 'granting' user?

Comment: I don't follow.  How is that any different than Tom's existing role?

Comment: Tom's real role is a read-write user, but only on certain databases. I need to create these databases on the fly, but if Tom can't grant himself access to them then I'll need something that can. I just didn't really want a user that can access all the databases. It's not a *huge* deal, but I've still got my programmer's pout on =]

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any way to do that, unfortunately.  Your best bets are either to create a dedicated administrator or to use the technique described by perissf, but in that case you need to know the database names beforehand.

Comment: The database names will be something like panel_[int], so I could rattle off, say, 1000 sets of permissions, but that feels dirty (not least because of the confusion in a few years time when someone creates panel_1001). I've got a global superUser now, which is something I'd hoped to avoid. Never mind.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing correctly. It's by design. However what you can do is written in the Reference Manual:
"MySQL enables you to grant privileges on databases or tables that do not exist. For tables, the privileges to be granted must include the CREATE privilege. This behavior is by design, and is intended to enable the database administrator to prepare user accounts and privileges for databases or tables that are to be created at a later time."

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html#grant-privileges

Comment: As a consequence, the supposed procedure is that the superuser grants Tom the privileges to SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, etc on a number of datbases that do not exist yet: TOM_db1, TOM_db2, etc... and that TOM is free to create when he'll need to